# AnchorNode/Models are disappeared in android sceneform sdk

Tags: android, arcore, sceneform

Detect the plane in the sceneform/ArCore and add a few models on AnchorNode.
But Models are disappearing in the following cases.

1. Move phone faster
2. Lights are low
3. Blocking camera vision

So, Why is it Disappearing?

Does anyone have an idea, how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is natural because the 3 cases you listed up makes ARCore hard to track the feature points.
And surely, there is no way to overcome this issue because tracking feature points is ARCore's job and not yours.
I'd rather let users be aware that in some specific environment application might not work properly. Or you could go ask ARCore developers